# Topological Notation of a Dynamic Probabilistic Graph

Tags: probability, general-topology, graph-theory

I am trying to figure out how to formally describe a probabilistic directed graph. In plain English the properties of the graph are as follows :

A graph is comprised of a set of nodes each with 2 edges. These edges can connect at random with any other two nodes. While each node can set only two outgoing edges, it can recieve any number of incoming edges. Each node re-assigns its edges at an individual rate.

If I have described it right, those nodes which reassign edges more frequently will cluster in terms of network connectivity over time, since the chance of their finding one another is higher.

If anyone could suggest a way to formally state this, or an online reference to a similar problem, that would be very helpful.

Thanks in advance,

Neil

Comment: Does every node have out-degree exactly 2?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Well I would be interested in a more general solution but I only need one with an out degree of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random graph on $n$ vertices chosen uniformly at random from all directed graphs on $n$ vertices with each vertex having out-degree exactly 2 is typically denoted $\vec{\mathbb{G}}_{2\text{-out}}$. (In words, "G 2 out".)

In Alan Frieze and Michał Karoński's [recent book](https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/BOOK.pdf), they discuss the model $\vec{\mathbb{G}}_{k\text{-out}}$ as well as its undirected version $\mathbb{G}_{k\text{-out}}$, where you remove the orientation of the edges, in chapter 16.

Comment: Looks like that is the book I was looking for! Thanks.